# minify js and css in one go starting from html

Tags: javascript, minify

I am making a `js` widget, like a map, or a calendar field or something. This is the `index.html` I use while developing the widget:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>example page</title>

    <script src="somelib.js"></script>
    <script src="someotherlib.js"></script>
    <script src="awesomelib.js"></script>
    <script src="spectacularlib.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="some.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="widget"></div>

    <script>
        myapp(document.getElementById('widget'));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not using a framework like angular or react. I am coding along in `app.js`, and add libraries as I need them to `index.html`.

Then comes a time I want to distribute my widget to the world. To do that, I would like to

- minify all referenced js files in index.html
- minify all css files

so that users of my widget can just include `widget.js` and `widget.css` and be good to go.

Is there something I can use that does that for me **with minimal hassle**? Something like

```
$ magictool index.html
- nice html you have. let me parse that and see what I need to do...
- oh, you have somelib.js. let me minify that for you and put it in dist.js
- oh, you have someotherlib.js. let me minify that for you and put it in dist.js
- oh, you have awesomelib.js. let me minify that for you and put it in dist.js
- oh, you have spectacularlib.js. let me minify that for you and put it in dist.js
- oh, you have app.js. let me minify that for you and put it in dist.js
- oh, you have some.css. let me minify that for you and put it in dist.css
- oh, you have app.css. let me minify that for you and put it in dist.css
! dist.js and dist.css created!
```

that reads `index.html` and creates a `dist.js` and `dist.css`.

Comment: Browserify is one of the magic tools: http://browserify.org/

Answer (score -1):

You can use **[Browserify](http://browserify.org)** to get that one bundle of `.js` files.

After installing the magic tool from `npm` or `yarn`, you can do the following:

`browserify js/*.js -o js/bundle.js -d`

And then just include the `bundle.js` in your `index.html`.

**Note:** I will update the answer for `css`.

Comment: Doing `browserify js/*.js` would get all js files in some random order, not in the correct order they appear in the index.html file, and so the created bundle.js file would not work. Or you have to use `require` to include your scripts.